# How do I make a batch log file?

Tags: batch-file, logging

How do I make a log file from this code. This has been answered a ton, but this file is huge and I want a simple log file. As you see I also tried to add a log file names RandomNamesLog.log. See if the output goes there.

I want all the code to be outputted into the log file, with error messages and confirm messages, like removing the @ECHO OFF value.
If you need more on what I want, please tell me.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in 
('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do ( set 
"DEL=%%a" )
ECHO Random Names
ECHO Written By: Trevor T
ECHO UltimateGuidesPro.blogspot.com
ECHO.
ECHO.

REM Randomly renames every file in a directory.

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM 0 = Rename the file randomly.
REM 1 = Prepend the existing file name with randomly generated string.
SET PrependOnly=0

REM 1 = Undo changes according to the translation file.
REM This will only work if the file "__Translation.txt" is in the same 
folder.
REM If you delete the translaction file, you will not be able to undo 
the changes!
SET Undo=0


REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Do not modify anything below this line unless you know what you are doing.
REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET TranslationFile=_TranslatonData.txt
SET LogFile=_RandomNamesLog.log

IF NOT {%Undo%}=={1} (
REM Rename files
ECHO You are about to randomly rename every file in the following folder:
ECHO %~dp0
ECHO.
ECHO A file named %TranslationFile% will be created which allows you to undo this.
ECHO Warning: If %TranslationFile% is lost/deleted, this action cannot be undone.
ECHO Type "OK" to continue.
SET /P Confirm=
IF /I NOT {!Confirm!}=={OK} (
    ECHO.
    ECHO Aborting.
    GOTO :EOF
)

ECHO Original Name/Random Name > %TranslationFile%
ECHO ------------------------- >> %TranslationFile%

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DIR /A:-D /B') DO (
    IF NOT %%A==%~nx0 (
        IF NOT %%A==%TranslationFile% (
            SET Use=%%~xA
            IF {%PrependOnly%}=={1} SET Use=_%%A

            SET NewName=!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!!Use!
            ECHO %%A/!NewName!>> %TranslationFile%

            RENAME "%%A" "!NewName!"

   ECHO ----------------------------------------------------- >> %TranslationFile%
   ECHO Designed by Trevor T | UltimateGuidesPro.blogspot.com >> %TranslationFile%
   ECHO. >> %TranslationFile%
   ECHO WARNING: THIS FILE REQUIRED TO UNDO RANDOM NAMING! THE FILE CAN BE MOVED AS LONG AS IT IS IN THE FOLDER WHEN USING THE UNDO RANDOM NAMES FUNCTION! >> %TranslationFile%
 ECHO +---------+
 ECHO | Credits |  
 ECHO +---------+
 Echo.
 ECHO Original Random Names script created by
 call :colorEcho 0a "Jason Faulkner"
 call :colorEcho 0a "HowToGeek.com"
 ECHO ---------------------------------------
 ECHO Script created by
 call :colorEcho 0a "Trevor T"
 ECHO -------------------------------------------
 ECHO Color Text system created by
 call :colorEcho 0a "Visual Magic, user on Stack Exchange"
 ECHO Type "Exit" to quit
 GOTO :Exit
 :Exit
 SET /P Confirm=
IF /I NOT {!Confirm!}=={Exit} (
    ECHO.
    ECHO Please try again
    GOTO :Exit2
Exit 
 :Exit2
SET /P Confirm=
IF /I NOT {!Confirm!}=={OK} (
    ECHO.
    ECHO Please try again
    GOTO :Exit

 )
    )
)
) ELSE (
ECHO UNDO MODE
IF NOT EXIST %TranslationFile% (
    ECHO Missing translation file: %TranslationFile%
ECHO Please make sure %TranslationFile% is in the location of the random files. Otherwise it will give this error.
    PAUSE
    GOTO :EOF
)
ECHO Undoing...
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%A IN (%TranslationFile%) DO RENAME "%%B" "%%A"
DEL /F /Q %TranslationFile% 
ECHO Completed Undo!
Pause
)
Exit
REM This is the color text code. Don't touch this, unless you know a better way to use color text.
:colorEcho 
echo off 
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2" 
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul 
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i
```

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten your script fixing all of the problems I could see and removing the pointless code to add colored text.

Test it to see if it works as it should adding whatever you think I've missed.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

ECHO Random Names
ECHO Written By: Trevor T
ECHO UltimateGuidesPro.blogspot.com
ECHO.

REM Randomly renames every file in a directory.

REM 0 = Rename the file randomly.
REM 1 = Prepend the existing file name with randomly generated string.
SET "PrependOnly=0"

REM 1 = Undo changes according to the translation file.
REM This will only work if the file "_TranslationData.txt" is in the same folder.
REM If you delete the translaction file, you will not be able to undo the changes!
SET "Undo=0"

REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Do not modify anything below this line unless you know what you are doing.
REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET "TranslationFile=_TranslationData.txt"
IF "%Undo%"=="1" GOTO UNDOIT

ECHO You are about to randomly rename every file in the following folder:
ECHO %CD%
ECHO.
CHOICE /M "Do you want to continue "
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
    ECHO.
    ECHO Aborting.
    TIMEOUT -1
    GOTO :EOF
)

ECHO A file named %TranslationFile% will be created which allows you to undo this.
ECHO Warning: If %TranslationFile% is lost/deleted, this action cannot be undone.
(
    ECHO ;Original Name/Random Name
    ECHO ;-------------------------
    FOR %%A IN (*) DO IF NOT "%%A"=="%~nx0" IF NOT "%%A"=="%TranslationFile%" (
        SET "Use=%%~xA"
        IF "%PrependOnly%"=="1" SET "Use=_%%A"
        SET "NewName=!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!!Use!"
        ECHO %%A/!NewName!
        REN "%%A" "!NewName!"
    )
    ECHO ;-----------------------------------------------------
    ECHO ;Designed by Trevor T ^| UltimateGuidesPro.blogspot.com
    ECHO.
    ECHO ;WARNING: THIS FILE REQUIRED TO UNDO RANDOM NAMING!
    ECHO ; THE FILE CAN BE MOVED AS LONG AS IT IS IN THE FOLDER WHEN USING THE UNDO RANDOM NAMES FUNCTION!
)>"%TranslationFile%"

ECHO +---------+
ECHO ^| Credits ^|  
ECHO +---------+
ECHO.
ECHO Original Random Names script created by Jason Faulkner @ HowToGeek.com
ECHO -------------------------------------------
ECHO Script created by Trevor T
ECHO -------------------------------------------
TIMEOUT -1
GOTO :EOF

:UNDOIT
ECHO UNDO MODE
IF NOT EXIST "%TranslationFile%" (
    ECHO Missing translation file: %TranslationFile%
    ECHO Please make sure %TranslationFile% is in the location of the random files. Otherwise it will give this error.
    TIMEOUT -1
    GOTO :EOF
)
ECHO Undoing...
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=1-2 DELIMS=/" %%A IN ("%TranslationFile%") DO REN "%%B" "%%A"
DEL /F "%TranslationFile%" 
ECHO Completed Undo!
TIMEOUT -1
GOTO :EOF
```

Once you are happy with it edit your opening question explaining what it is you want to have in the log file and how you need it to look.

Comment: Thanks @compo! That really helped

Answer (score 0):

I use this. it seems to work.
It just starts a log file and maintains logs.
You can set logpath and logname (base name) then you call this create_logfile

It creates a semi-random log file.

Now you write to the set logfile

I'm not an advanced coder. Please feel free to correct:

```
@echo off
rem
echo %date% %TIME%

rem Log File Path
if "%logpath%" == "" set logpath=%~dp0
if "%logpath:~-1%" == "\" set logpath=%logpath:~0,-1%

rem Make log file name
if "%logname%" == "" set logname=log

set t=%TIME: =0%
set d=%DATE%
set logfilename=%logname%_%d:~12,2%%d:~4,2%%d:~7,2%%t:~0,2%%t:~3,2%%t:~6,2%.log
set t=
set d=
rem Test
echo full log file name = %logfilename%
echo find base log name = %logfilename:~0,-17%
echo log path = %logpath%

rem Logs to maintain
set /a dellog=5

rem Find file to delete
set var=
set /a cnt=0
set fltodel=
set fstfle=
for %%a in (%logpath%\%logname%*.log) do (
    set var=%%a
    call set /a "cnt+=1"
    echo %%cnt%%| findstr /l "1" >nul && (call set fstfle=%%var%%)
    echo %%cnt%%| findstr /l "%dellog%" >nul && (call set fltodel=%%fstfle%%)
)
rem Delete old log
echo file to delete %fltodel%
if exist %fltodel% (del /q %fltodel%) else (echo "%fltodel%" does not exist. nothing to delete.)

echo tryed to delete


rem Create Log File and logfile attribute
set logfile=%logpath%\%logfilename%
if exist %logfile% (
echo start logging... "%~0" on %date% %time% >> %logfile%
) ELSE (
echo Start Log for "%~0" on %date% %time% > %logfile%
)
```